# How do I back up Windows 10 installed programs and settings and then restore after update?

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, windows-10-upgrade, restore

I am currently running Windows 10 Pro 1709 and want to upgrade to 1803

I've been hitting a ton of weird errors trying to upgrade (its a hand built PC) and troubleshooting hasn't gotten my anywhere (see my other SuperUser post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1346402/windows-10-1803-upgrade-fails-with-access-violation-code-c0000005-error))

I have decided the best option is to backup my files and installed programs, and just reinstall them on a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro 1803.

I can back up my files just fine, but how do I backup my installed programs?

How do I restore them after the upgrade?

Comment: You can use the following software to see if it helps. https://www.easeus.com/pc-transfer/backup-and-restore-installed-applications-windows-10.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While *technically* possible, the reality is you cant.  There are just to many factors in Windows based application installs.  Does the application modify the registry?  If so, is it in one or more places?  Does it have multiple folders?  Does it register DLLs?  Are there hidden files or folders it uses?  The list goes on and on.

Trying to figure all this information out will take more time than it would to just reinstall all the applications.  If you are going to do a fresh install, your best bet is to reinstall each and every application to make sure there is no issues down the line.